# Selecting 'Computer' or 'Libraries' in Java's JFileChooser yields a strange File object

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I'm using JFileChooser in a very standard "Save As" situation. A am generating a file, and the user is picking where to save it.

Confusingly, the user can pick number of "not real" folders. In Windows 7 they are: Computer, Network, Libraries, Homegroup. When I invoke chooser.getSelectedFile(); I get a file object, but it is very odd. It makes sense that this would be a strange File object since it doesn't correspond to a file which could actually exist. If I try to use the file, for example calling getCanonicalPath, I get an IOException. But what doesn't make sense, as a programmer, is my lack of information about this File object or its parent.

I would like to configure the JFileChooser so that it doesn't permit the user to make such a selection. Thus far I've found that using this works:

```
setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

However the user is then picking the directory of the new file but not the name.

Alternately, I would like to at least explain why they can't save in that location. All my attempts to get the name, e.g. "Computer," "Network," or "Libraries" have failed. Using Java 6 on Windows 7, FileSystemView methods like isComputerNode and isFileSystem, which should address this question, don't help.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

public class JChooserTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setSelectedFile(new File("C:/foo.txt"));
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Save As");
    chooser.setFileHidingEnabled(true);
    chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(javax.swing.JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);
    Component parentComponent = null; // is not null in the real world 
    int state=chooser.showDialog(parentComponent, "Save As");
    if (state == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) return;

    File dest = chooser.getSelectedFile();

    try {
        System.out.println("Valid Destination: " + dest.getCanonicalPath());

    } catch (IOException ex) { // getCanonicalPath() threw IOException

        File parent = dest.getParentFile();

        FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();

        //log.error("Error determining the CanonicalPath of " + dest, ex);
        System.out.println("dest.getName: " + dest.getName());
        System.out.println("parent.getName: " + parent.getName());          
        System.out.println("getSystemDisplayName of dest: " + fsv.getSystemDisplayName(dest));
        System.out.println("getSystemDisplayName of parent: " + fsv.getSystemDisplayName(parent));          
        System.out.println("getSystemTypeDescription of dest: " + fsv.getSystemTypeDescription(dest));
        System.out.println("getSystemTypeDescription of parent: " + fsv.getSystemTypeDescription(parent));
        System.out.println("isFileSystem of dest: " + fsv.isFileSystem(dest));
        System.out.println("isFileSystem of parent: " + fsv.isFileSystem(parent));
        System.out.println("isComputerNode of dest: " + fsv.isComputerNode(dest));
        System.out.println("isComputerNode of parent: " + fsv.isComputerNode(parent));          
        System.out.println("dest" + dest.isDirectory());
        System.out.println("parent" + parent.isDirectory());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: As you've discovered, there are differences between `directories` (actual physical file directories) and `folders`, which may not represent anything on disk at all (like `Printers`) or multiple disk directories (like `My Photos` or `Libraries`). Raymond Chen of Microsoft wrote a short blog post a while back that explains the basic difference. You can find it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/16/10129908.aspx); it may help visualize things.

Comment: Interesting. So "Computer," "Network," and "Libraries" are all  "Virtual folders" aka "folders-which-are-not-directories." That makes sense. From a Java perspective, I'm still at a loss as to how to identify these, other than invoking getCanonicalPath() and trapping the exception. Kind of frustrating that FileSystemView seems designed to do this kind of thing, but doesn't actually do so, in the stock JRE for Windows.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry I can't help with the Java perspective, as I'm not a Java person. :) I'm familiar with the WinAPI and the Windows Shell, which is why I knew what the issue was you were having (and thought of Raymond's article,  which took a bit to find again <g>).

Answer (score 1):

The returned `File` object has a name of `::{031E4825-7B94-4DC3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}`.  Unfortunately, this is actually the name of the libraries folder, and it exists only in Explorer's imagination, not to anyone else.

For example, create a folder somewhere (for example, on your desktop), called `foo.{031E4825-7B94-4DC3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}`, and open it.  Explorer will think it's the Libraries folder, but everything else will be awfully confused:

```
 Directory of C:\Users\Faux\Desktop\lol.{031E4825-7B94-4DC3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}

17/02/2012  08:06 pm    <DIR>          .
17/02/2012  08:06 pm    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  794,214,469,632 bytes free
```

As to how to convince file chooser to not show them, I have no idea.  I'd suggest trying `getCanonicalPath()`, catching the exception (as you are) and returning it to the user; suggesting they pick somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah I may just catch the exception and ask them to pick a different folder. I was hoping to say 'You picked Libraries but that isn't a valid destination' as opposed to the more generic 'You picked an invalid destination'