# Java - Dealing with Libraries in Windows 7 (Such as Documents, Pictures, etc.)

Tags: java, io, text-files, filewriter

Windows treats libraries differently from regular folders and paths. Thus when I use this block of code to create a text file:

```
File filePath = fc.getSelectedFile();
```

... More irrelevant stuff...

```
File outputText = new File(filePath.getParentFile(), "Decrypted.txt");

    try
        {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outputText); //Write everything to the file.
        fw.write(messageOut);
        fw.close(); //DON'T FORGET TO CLOSE THE FILE!
        }
    catch (IOException e)
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It works if the file is in, say, the Desktop folder, but if I try to put it in the My Pictures Library, I get this error message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ::{031E4825-7B94-4DC3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}\Pictures.library-ms\Decrypted.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
at code.Crypto.decrypt(Crypto.java:57)
at code.Crypto.main(Crypto.java:27)
```

Is there a way for me to fix this?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug, tested and confirmed on my system as well with java 7 update4 32bit.

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
//select and enter a name for a file under libraries (with windows look and feel 
//select 'desktop' in the left pane, then libraries->pictures)
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file); //<-- FileNotFoundException
    fw.write("foo bar");
    fw.close();
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: ::{031E4825-7B94-4DC3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}\Pictures.library-ms\hej.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
at test.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

An ugly workaround could be to specify a file filter that filters out those, see:

[Selecting 'Computer' or 'Libraries' in Java's JFileChooser yields a strange File object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334531/selecting-computer-or-libraries-in-javas-jfilechooser-yields-a-strange-file)

Comment: Thanks. At least I know it wasn't my fault.